# Is there a good tweak for the Delphi code editor?

Tags: delphi, ide

One of the things I most want in Delphi is that it had a better indent control we see in many simple code editors like Notepad++ or even Eclipse and Dreamweaver.

The plus/minus icon to hide or expand codes is a very good tool for a coder. It would be even great

Another very good tool would be a annotation marker with inbox comments separated from the pascal code, like [diigo](http://www.diigo.com) service or the Microsoft Office Word revision tab that lays in the right side of the document page.

Does that exists for Delphi as an add-in tool?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is a question from 2009 about best approaches that was never touched. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091043/best-practice-in-delphi-rapid-application-development-in-term-of-reusability but when I make such questions, they are deleted extremely fast. :-( wonder why...

Comment: Can't wonder to think what is the "_this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion_" about this question. There was a question, and then, there was the answer. Period.

Comment: Wondering who is the Eric Cartman behind all that anger... :-P

Comment: I would close vote you just for taking a picture of your monitor because you don't know how to hit Ctrl+PrintScreen. Seriously. ;-)

Comment: @WarrenP this is very funny. But this picture is the logo of a Delphi blog. I think he did that on propose. :)

Comment: :-)  Before this was in cnpack it was in a popular Delphi 7 add on called CodeRush. Sadly codeRush never made the leap to modern Delphi and its author moved onto making Visual Studio add-on also named CodeRush.

Comment: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-google-maps-api-v3-from-delphi-part-i-basic-functionality/

Comment: At http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ when you going to ask a question it says: "_We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed_". I think that prefer means Prefer, not Only... \;-)

Comment: Nope it pretty much means "Stackoverflow is not a forum or a discussion center".

Comment: I thought that the `rad` tag was for `Rapid Application Development` :-|]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the vertical lines effect from CnPack.
http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en
It's got some other goodies too, like "eval swap" which transposes a := b; into b := a;
and a great one called "convert to string", which is great for converting things like long SQL statements into

```
'strings that' + #13#10 +
'span' + #13#10 +
'multiple lines.'
```

Comment: I have downloaded it and it's fine. Really works fine. Thanks. **Everyone who uses Delphi should use it.**

Comment: @EASI, that was actually the first thing I was looking how to turn off. Voted to reopen this question. Even if it's *not constructive* from a StackOverflow point of view, it doesn't deserve to be deleted (since there's a one delete vote and I know what random close/delete voters can do).

Answer (score 0):

I also found Castalia Add-On powered By Embarcadero:

http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/delphibasics.html?r=a

It has syntax highlight, code refactoring, code metrics and smart paste.